# Angular property showing as undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

It seems that the data is loaded via a service but when we try to access the specific properties in a loop, it shows as undefined.

However, when we log the whole object, it shows that there is actual data. The code snippet and console logs are given below..

```
this.projectMapView.forEach(mapview => {
                                console.log(mapview);
                                console.log("Lat: " + mapview.LatitudeY);
                            });

{id: 31854, projectNo: 'Project-123', projectName: 'Energy Savings', longitudeX: -123.456, latitudeY: 50.1456}
projects.component.ts:169 Lat: undefined
```

Comment: The property casing is wrong. Should be `mapview.latitudeY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the casing. In javascript properties are case sensitive so you have to use `mapview.latitudeY`. Note the lowercase `l` in `latitudeY`.

Comment: Thank you . the issue is resolved. But the surpiring part for me is that the typescript class has these in uppercase and well the .net core class. why it was then assuming the first character to be small is confusing to me